# Higher order gradients defined on a Riemmanian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. I know that the gradient of a smooth function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb R$ can be defined implicitly using the metric:
$$
g(\nabla f, X) = df(X), \quad \forall X \in \Gamma(TM)
$$
I have seen the higher order gradient $\nabla^k f$, $k \geq 1$ in the same context, without an explicit definition. How is $\nabla^k$ defined? By (semi-)logical concatenation of symbols, I assumed it would be a recursive definition like:
$$
g(\nabla^k f, X) = (\nabla^{k-1} f)(df(X)), \forall X \in \Gamma(TM)
$$
Is this right, or is the definition something else?

Comment: Do you know about affine connections?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Unfortunately, I do not.

Comment: Then you should read about connections since this is a standard tool for answering such questions. Pretty much any differential geometry textbook will cover this material.

Comment: Here's the basic fact: If you have a tensor $T$, there is a standard way to define the covariant derivative of $T$ (which you can find somewhere), $\nabla T$, which is also a tensor. Now you just proceed by induction. If you have defined the tensor $T = \nabla^kf$, then you can define $\nabla^{k+1}f = \nabla T$.